# gitignore include specific subfolder

Tags: git, gitignore

I code in Python and like to include virtual envs inside my project folder. So, I have to put a line in .gitignore to prevent it from tracking venv. But, there is a particular subfolder inside of venv that I want to keep track of.

This isn't working:

`.gitignore`

```
venv
!venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nhlscrapi
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

```
/venv/**
!/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nhlscrapi
```

Comment: You need to do the following:

`venv/*`

`!venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nhlscrapi`

Note: The trailing /* is important:

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following lines in .gitignore

`venv/*
!venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nhlscrapi`

Note: The trailing /* is important here

I had the same scenario and it worked for me like a charm. :)